# Breaking line in a separate file

Tags: python

My mission is to get multiple ip addresses, 
write them in a new file, and make each address appear in a separate line.

So, I get to `file.write(ip)`. Now what?

I've tried adding \n `file.write(ip \n)`

and I've tried `file.write(\n)`. none of that works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add more code?  Is `ip` all of the ip addresses or is the code you have part of a for loop?

Comment: I presume you actually  have `ip+"\n"`?

Comment: Please give us some minimal, but *verifiable* code so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make use of Python's `with` statement. This will ensure your file is automatically closed after it is used. Assuming you have your addresses stored as a list, the following approach should help to get you started:

```
ip_addresses = ['1.0.0.1', '1.0.0.2', '1.0.0.3', '1.0.0.4']

with open('ip.txt', 'w') as f_ip:
    for ip_address in ip_addresses:
        f_ip.write('{}\n'.format(ip_address))
```

Giving you an output file called `ip.txt` as follows:

```
1.0.0.1
1.0.0.2
1.0.0.3
1.0.0.4
```